# Starting celery in flask: AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'user_options'

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, redis, celery

I try to start a Celery worker server from a command line:

```
celery -A server application worker --loglevel=info
```

The code and folder path:

```
server.py  
application/controllers/routes.py
```

**server.py**

```
app = Flask(__name__)  
from application.controllers import routes  
app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=5051,debug=True)
```

**route.py**

```
from flask import Flask,  
from celery import Celery
from server import app 


app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0' 

celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)

@celery.task()  
def add_together(self, count):  
   return "First success"

@app.route("/queing")  
def testsfunction():    
    count = 1  
    add_together.delay(count)  
    return "cool"
```

Trace back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 770, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 309, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 477, in setup_app_from_commandline
    user_preload = tuple(self.app.user_options['preload'] or ())
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'user_options'
```

I got this error when I'm running a celery worker in terminal.

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: added the complete trace back

Comment: i thing i have missed in celery worker will you help me out ??

Comment: you have confused the celery and flask app objects. you have passed a Flask app to celery

Comment: and route.py appears to be missing a few lines - where is `app` defined in there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just run the celery with this command instead of yours:

```
celery -A application.controllers.routes:celery worker --loglevel=info
```

this will solve your current problem however your codes have a plenty of mistakes for example if you want to have a self argument inside your `add_together` function you you should declare a task like this:

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
```

Comment: for me the one that worked is `celery -A server:celery worker`

Answer (score -2):

It seems like you have typo mistake:

```
def add_together(self, count):
```

to

```
def add_together(count):
```