# I cannot launch Flower monitor server for Flask/Celery simple project

Tags: python, vagrant, celery, flower

I have a simple Flask/Celery project based on [this tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask).

The folder tree is the following:

```
ctest\  
- templates\  
  - index.html  
- app.py  
- __init__.py
```

The `index.html` file is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sum</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Sum a number with 100</h2>
    {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
    <p style="color: red;">{{ message }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

    <form method="POST">
        <p>Use number: <input type="text" name="number" value="{{ number }}"></p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add in 30 secs">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and the `app.py` is:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, session, flash, redirect, url_for
from celery import Celery
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

# initialize Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

# Celery broker and backend configuration
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

# Initialize extensions
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'top-secret!'

# Initialize Celery
celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'], backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)


@celery.task()
def make_async_sum(number):
    with app.app_context():
        logger.info("Executing....!")
        return int(number) + 100

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    # take the number from the form
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', number=session.get('number',''))
    number = request.form['number']
    session['number'] = number

    if request.form['submit'] == 'Add':
        # add now
        make_async_sum.delay(number)
        flash('Adding %s to 100'%number)
    else:
        # add later
        make_async_sum.apply_async(args=[number], countdown=30)
        flash('Adding %s to 100 , in 30 secs' % number)

    return redirect( url_for('index') )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # use that host to be open from anywhere [cause I want to access it from outside the VM]
    # use port 8181 [or smthing else] and not 8080
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8181)
```

It is running inside a Vagrant VM. I can access the `index.html` from my host browser. I can SSH in the VM and tap into the worker to see the tasks being processed with `celery worker -A app.celery --loglevel=info` .

But, I cannot start the Flower monitoring tool for this project.

I try `flower -A ctest` from the dir path right above `ctest\` but I get the following error.

```
Unknown Celery version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/flower", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('flower==0.9.1', 'console_scripts', 'flower')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flower/__main__.py", line 11, in main
    flower.execute_from_commandline()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 279, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 489, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self._handle_user_preload_options(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 494, in _handle_user_preload_options
    user_preload = tuple(self.app.user_options['preload'] or ())
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'user_options'
```

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at those:

1. [AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'user_options'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884951/attributeerror-flask-object-has-no-attribute-user-options?answertab=votes#tab-top)
2. [Starting celery in flask: AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'user_options'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333727/starting-celery-in-flask-attributeerror-flask-object-has-no-attribute-user)

They have a similar problem (not with `flower` though).

I would try calling flower as follows:

```
celery flower -A ctest.app
```

or

```
celery flower -A ctest.app.celery
```

Comment: No prob mate :) ! Να 'σαι καλά!!